# Are all places delivered by the Google Places API displayed on the Google Maps Base Layer?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Are all places delivered by the Google Places API displayed on the Google Maps MapTypeId.ROADMAP by default?  That is, I do not need to query the places API and display them on the Google Maps MapTypeId.ROADMAP because by default they already show us a labels?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  The ROADMAP type show many prominent places on the map to help provide context, but they are by no means the entire listing of places that might be found via the Places API for a location.